# How to extract 15GB rar file containing mkv video files

Tags: 7-zip, extract, rar

I have a `.rar` file that contains 15 GB of mkv video files. I am using Windows 7 64 bit and all hard disk partitions are NTFS. There is 500 GB of hard disk space and 4 GB of RAM. I have tried extracting with 7zip, but it did not work. 7zip is automatically closed after finishing part of the file. Is there any other way to extract this file with 7zip or other means?

Comment: try WinRAR - though if the file is corrupt you might need the associated PAR files to reconstruct it

Comment: WinRAR is not working. It's not corrupted file.

Comment: Use the Test function in 7-zip or WinRAR

Answer (score 0):

the native tool for .rar files is WinRar. Give that one ago.

I've resorted to winrar for other archive types too when some other archive manager is causing me grief, because winrar generally seems more robust when it comes to cases where there's "a bit more" than what you'd normally find, such as a .zip file with tens of thousands of files in it.

If that doesn't work, have you checked the integrity of the rar file? I believe 7zip can test this for you.